# Can you move during your reaction in a ready action?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, readied-action, reactions

So let's say that the party or the baddies want to dive a target all at once, but they are far apart on the turn order. Can the divers all do a ready action and then all jump in at once?

Example:

Turn order is:

1. PC1
2. PC2
3. NPC1
4. PC3
5. PC4
6. NPC2

Can NPC1 do a ready action of "when NPC2 moves in to attack a PC, I move in to attack the same PC" and then move and attack as the reaction?

Comment: Hi Adam, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: Purple Monkey has a great answer below. As an aside, it is also a commonly-used practice for GMs to run entire blocks of "monster" on the same initiative.  e.g. a fight with 6 kobolds and 2 goblins, GMs will often run the 6 kobolds on a single imitative for simplicity.  It can also streamline situations like this.

Answer (score 18):

## You can move *or* attack, not both.

As stated in the Ready action description on page 193 of the PHB:

> Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger, **or** you choose to move up to your speed in response to it.

Comment: If you are also hasted could you use the haste action to attack and the move as the redied action?

Comment: @SamLacrumb That sounds like an interesting question in it's own right.  The answer is no, but it's an interesting edge case to bring up.

Comment: @GcL Why not? You can't use the haste action to attack-and-move as a Ready, but you very much can use the haste action to attack (once), then use the normal action to Ready movement for later. It may not be the most effective or efficient thing to do, but I don't recall anything preventing it.

Comment: Yes.  I misread that as using the haste action to attack and move as the readied action.